# Jest + Vue vm properties and methods unresolved in IntelliJ

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, jestjs

My Vue Component:

```
 data() { 
    return {
      test: false,
    }
 },
 methods: {
    setTestToTrue() {
       this.test = true
 },
```

My JestJs test

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of the warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require adding special support for `wrapper.vm`, as the methods are added dynamically in runtime and thus can't be resolved statically

Please vote for [WEB-51228](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51228) to be notified on any progress with it